# Spring boot application cannot fetch data from database

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get the information of a customer by customer id in Spring boot. After hitting in postman, it says that the id is not found. Here I am sharing my code for better understanding.

This is my Entity class

```
package com.example.crud.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customers {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "customerid")
    private Integer customerId;

    @Column(name = "customername")
    private String customerName;

    @Column(name = "contactname")
    private String contactName;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "postalcode")
    private String postalcode;

    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;

}
```

This is the Base Service class. The real implementation of get By Id and Update method. The aim of this class and method is to reduce the number of code. Whatever the number of fields in a class has, it will map the object automatically.

```
package com.example.crud.service;

import com.example.crud.repository.CustomerRepository;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.Optional;

public abstract class BaseService < T, ID extends Integer> {

    protected JpaRepository <T, ID> repository;

    public BaseService(JpaRepository<T, ID> repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Transactional (readOnly = true)
    public T baseFindById (ID id){
        Optional<T> entity = repository.findById(id);
        if(entity.isEmpty()){
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Entity with ID " + id + " not found");
        }
        return entity.get();
    }

    @Transactional
    public T baseUpdate(T entity){
        return repository.save(entity);
    }

}
```

The Customer repository Interface

```
package com.example.crud.repository;

import com.example.crud.model.Customers;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public  interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository <Customers, Integer> {
}
```

Customer service class

```
package com.example.crud.service;


@Service
public class CustomerService extends BaseService <Customers, Integer>{

    @Autowired
    public CustomerService(CustomerRepository repository) {
        super(repository);
    }
}
```

This is the controller class.

```
package com.example.crud.controller;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer/")
public class CustomerController {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Customers findCustomerById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return customerService.baseFindById(id);
    }
    @PutMapping ("{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Customers updateCustomers(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Customers customers){
        customers.setCustomerId(id);
        return customerService.baseUpdate(customers);
    }
}
```

after using postman with the link ***http://localhost:8080/customer/2***,

*jakarta.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Entity with ID 2 not found at com.example.crud.service.BaseService.baseFindById(BaseService.java:23)*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUudI.png)

Comment: Please always share the complete stacktrace

Comment: Don't post images with details that could be posted as text.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with
@GetMapping("/customer")

or
@PutMapping ("/{id}")

Answer (score 0):

Refactor @RequestMapping("/customer/") to @RequestMapping("/customer") and remove slash from @GetMapping("/{id}") slash